# Extract rows and columns of a tensor using indices

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a 2-D tensor `x`, which is a placeholder `x = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[None, 100])`.
Now in the graph, I want to extract randomly `50%` rows of x.
Here is what I tried:

```
idxs = tf.range(tf.shape(x)[0])
ridxs = tf.random_shuffle(idxs)[: int(tf.shape(x)[0] * 0.5)]
x = tf.gather(x, ridxs, axis=0)
```

It throws the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main_gcn_random_sampling.py", line 76, in <module>
    model = GCN_RANDOM_SAMPLING(FLAGS.learning_rate, num_input, num_classes, hidden_dimensions=hidden_sizes, act=tf.nn.relu)
  File "/home/tiendh/Projects/EPooling/gcn_random_sampling.py", line 63, in __init__
    ridxs = tf.random_shuffle(idxs)[: int(tf.shape(x)[0] * 0.5)]
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'Tensor' and 'float'
```

I could declare another placeholder for predefined indices, but it would look ugly. Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's almost right, but:

1. You have to cast to `tf.shape(x)[0]` to float before multiplying by `0.5`.
2. You cannot use `int` to cast a tensor data type, you need to use [`tf.cast`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/cast).

```py
idxs = tf.range(tf.shape(x)[0])
num_half_idx = tf.cast(tf.cast(tf.shape(x)[0], tf.float32) * 0.5, tf.int32)
ridxs = tf.random_shuffle(idxs)[: num_half_idx]
x = tf.gather(x, ridxs, axis=0)
```

Note that, if you are always getting a 50% of the rows, you can also simply do:

```py
idxs = tf.range(tf.shape(x)[0])
ridxs = tf.random_shuffle(idxs)[: tf.shape(x)[0] // 2]
x = tf.gather(x, ridxs, axis=0)
```

Comment: I tried and it still throws the error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'Tensor' and 'float'`

Comment: @lenhhoxung Yes, sorry I missed that, I think it's correct now.